# Prevent same row being selected in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, parallel-processing

I have been given the task of creating a "Mass Crawler" which completely relies on proxies inside a database. Here's a simple overview in what I'm attempting to achieve :

- 1 x CronJob Bootstrap file - This is the file which sends 50 parallel **curl** requests to the **individual crawler** file
- 1 x Individual Crawler file - This is supposed to grab a **UNIQUE** row (proxy) from the database which another process hasn't selected.

I've had a look into the `TRANSACTIONS` with mySQL, but I still believe doing this wouldn't help as the query would be getting executed at the exact same time for each individual crawler process.

Here's kind of the idea I had in my head for the individual crawler file :

```
$db = new MysqliDb("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

$db->connect();
$db->startTransaction();
$db->where("last_used", array("<" => "DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 SECOND)"));
$proxies = $db->get("proxies", 1);
if(count($proxies) == 1) {

    //complete any scraping that needs to be done

    //update the database to say the proxy has just been used
    $db->where("id", $accounts[0]['id']);
    $db->update("proxies", array("last_used", date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));

    //commit the complete transaction
    $db->commit();
}
$db->disconnect();
```

Would that above example be the correct way to use the mySQL `TRANSACTION` feature and assure **ALL** parallel queries selected different rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a column in the table that indicates that the row is in use by one of the crawler processes. Your first `SELECT` should look for `WHERE in_use = 0`; it needs to use the `FOR UPDATE` clause to lock the rows that are processed, though.

```
SELECT *
FROM proxies
WHERE in_use = 0
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;
```

I don't know how to write that query with the DB API you're using; you may need to use its function for performing raw queries.

Then updates that row to `SET in_use = 1`. By doing both operations in a transaction, you ensure that no other process will get that row.

When it's done processing the row, it can `SET in_use = 0`.

Comment: `select` will not lock rows even inside `start transaction`, `select for update` will work thou

Comment: Would I still be required to use transactions for this? or would this query be fine to use outside of transactions?

Comment: You either have to use transactions or `LOCK TABLE`.